# KeePass and First Launch Confirmation

Tags: keepass

I hope this is the right place to ask such a silly question, but here goes (I would've used IRC for this, if I could've found a channel for KeePass).

So, I just installed KeePass 2, and on first launch the application asked me something probably important, **but I accidentally clicked the "deny"-button**, before I had the chance to read what it was about!

Can anyone tell me what KeePass asks on startup? (And possibly if I can/should enable it in settings?)

(I tried uninstalling & reinstalling the app, but it didn't ask it anymore!)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As memory serves, it asks what method of authentication you would like to use to access your passwords:

- Computer Account
- Password
- Key File

More info can be [found from keypass:](http://keepass.info/extensions/v2/docs/KeePass2-GS.pdf)

Comment: In the link you posted, it says: "On first launch of KeePass it will prompt you to enable (default) or disable automatic checks for updates." I believe it was just that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to remove the directory `C:\Users\`*you*`\AppData\Roaming\KeePass` or the file `KeePass.config.xml` inside instead of re-installing.